# Extract digital signature in pdf using python

Tags: python, pdf

I need to get the digitally signed signature content like name of signature and signed date and coordinate of the whole signature part.

I tried using different modules like pypdf2, pdfminer and endesive modules, Out of these endesive modules is giving whether the digital signature is there in that pdf document or not.

This is the code base to get whether signature is there or not by using endesive module.

```
   fname = 'filename'
   data = open(fname, 'rb').read()
   pdf.verify(data)

   The above code gives the following output.
   cert.issuer: OrderedDict([('common_name', 'Srikanth'), ('organization_name', ''), ('organizational_unit_name', ''), ('email_address', 'srikanth@yahoo.com'), ('country_name', 'India')])
cert.subject: OrderedDict([('common_name', 'Srikanth'), ('organization_name', ''), ('organizational_unit_name', ''), ('email_address', 'srikanth@yahoo.com'), ('country_name', 'India')])
Out[13]: (True, True, False)
```

Please see the below reference link to get the sample digital signature:
https://www.globalsign.com/en-in/blog/certifying-vs-approval-signatures-in-adobe/

I need to get the digital signature values like:
Person name: Daniel Farrel
Signed Date: 2017.10.05  08.44.11 -04'00'

Answer (score 2):

I looked into this a bit, and you seem to be doing everything right. The API to `endesive` does not return the signers, it uses them internally, but as a caller you do not have access to them [1].

Also, be careful, because it appears that the library does not verify all the signatures, only the first one [2].

[1] https://github.com/m32/endesive/blob/master/endesive/verifier.py#L104

[2] https://github.com/m32/endesive/issues/124

Answer (score 0):

use the aspose-pdf module.

```py
import aspose.pdf as pdf
from cryptography import x509

pdfSign = pdf.facades.PdfFileSignature()
pdfSign.bind_pdf("example.pdf")

if pdfSign.contains_signature():
    signs = pdfSign.get_sign_names(False)
    for item in signs:
        # -*signature part*-
        date = pdfSign.get_date_time(item)
        signer_name = pdfSign.get_signer_name(item)
        reason = pdfSign.get_reason(item)
        location = pdfSign.get_location(item)
        contact = pdfSign.get_contact_info(item)
        # -*cert part*-
        cert = pdfSign.extract_certificate(item)
        cert_content = cert.readall()
        cert = x509.load_der_x509_certificate(cert_content)
        # user name
        user = cert.subject.rfc4514_string()
        # expiration date
        start = cert.not_valid_before
        end = cert.not_valid_after
else:
    print("There is no signature in file.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Although signature validation is not covered, signer info could be extracted using pypdf and asn1crypto using the code described in [How to locate digital signatures in PDF files with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72556172/how-to-locate-digital-signatures-in-pdf-files-with-python/77515811#77515811)