# How to locate digital signatures in PDF files with python

Tags: python, pdf, digital-signature

I have a rather simple challenge, or so it appears at first. I have chosen the python to do this.

I have multiple PDF files for which I have to detect the digital signature (if it is there or not at all) and get some of the details from it if it is there. For example, in my PDF files, on the signature, there always is the email address for the person who signed it. Signatures without email would be exception cases.

How I have visualized it is that I should be able to find all the signature objects in the document and put them in an array or a list and then go over them checking their details. Is this possible and how one would locate them?

All I can find online is related to verifying the signatures or signing PDF files, which, although very important, is something I do not require.

**EDIT**

I've now managed to locate the Signature in my PDF file and get its contents. I do, however, struggle now with decoding the contents.

Current solution for finding the signature is just temporary as I had to use the index of the signature object to locate it. Different PDF documents will have different indexes for the signature index. However the type is 'Sig' so some sort of a loop can be implemented that checks the object Type and if it is 'Sig', then you've found a signature object. I'll later edit my post with final script.

The signature content type is `pdfreader.types.native.HexString`. I believe if I'd manage to decode the string, I'd be able to get the data I'm looking for. I've been trying to change it to bytes and then decode from bytes to either utf-8 or ascii, but in case of UTF-8 I get error `'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 1: invalid start byte` and in case of ascii I get error `'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)`

Any workarounds would be much appreciated.

**SOLUTION**

As pointed in the comments and as I started to suspect, the 'content' of signature would not hold any of the attributes I'd need. I noticed, that when outputting signature my output in console is not complete (Probably because I was using debug console in visual studio) and there are more attributes for digital signature. I found, that for my signatures, the email is under 'Name' attribute. The only challenge now was to find how many objects there are in my PDF file. For that I worked with string manipulations. I found that last trailer has a 'Size' attribute with the amount of objects. I did not manage to find it in the PDFTrailer object, hence the string manipulations. If there is any other way, it would be nice to share. Pardon the try-catch in the object loop at the end, much better is to check if object exists and and it has a type before reading it. Do not copy that and work out a proper solution.

```
from pdfreader import PDFDocument

filename = r"<filepath.pdf>"
fd = open(filename, "rb")
doc = PDFDocument(fd)
pdf_content = str(fd.read())
nr_of_obj = 0
nr_of_signatures = 0
signature_names = [] #in my case - emails
s_trailer = 'trailer'
s_startxref = 'startxref'

# +/- 2 at the end for new line character before and after the trailer
#Finding where last trailer of the document starts and ends

last_trailer_start = pdf_content.rfind(s_trailer)+len(s_trailer)+2
last_trailer_end = pdf_content.rfind(s_startxref)-2

#Putting the trailer together
trailer = ""
for i in range(last_trailer_start, last_trailer_end):
    trailer += pdf_content[i]

#Split the trailer attributes. Locate and read Size
trailer = trailer.split('/')
for attribute in trailer:
    if attribute.find('Size') >= 0:
        nr_of_obj = int(attribute.replace('Size','').strip())
        break

#Use the size to loop through objects. All the objects will not exist and not all will have Types. Hence try-catch.
for i in range(1, nr_of_obj):    
    try:
        raw_obj = doc.locate_object(i,0)
        obj = doc.build(raw_obj)
        if obj.Type == 'Sig':
            nr_of_signatures +=1
            signature_names.append(obj.Name)
    except:
        continue
print(nr_of_signatures)
print(signature_names)
```

Comment: *"in the PDF file, on the signature, there always is the email address for the person who signed it."* - no, that's not the case.

Comment: @mkl Sorry, I meant in my case there is always an email

Comment: *"The signature content type is `pdfreader.types.native.HexString`. I believe if I'd manage to decode the string, I'd be able to get the data I'm looking for. I've been trying to change it to bytes and then decode from bytes to either utf-8 or ascii..."* - that content is not a _text_ string, it is a _binary_ string containing a PKCS#7/CMS signature container.

Answer (score 2):

As of Nov. 2023, extracting signatures and signers from a PDF file still doesn't seem to be trivial. I wrote about this some years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32706905/308351). See also [Adobe Reader and Acrobat PDF Signatures description](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/DigSig/Acrobat_DigitalSignatures_in_PDF.pdf).

So here goes another attempt, now I use a recent version of **pypdf** for extracting fields and [**asn1crypto**](https://github.com/wbond/asn1crypto/blob/master/docs/readme.md) (besides **python-dateutil**) to parse the *PKCS7* signature. (It seems that *PyOpenSSL* and *cryptography* have deprecated loading pkcs7 data.) May be there are other libraries / packages which simplify the process.

Signature validation is out of scope.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import datetime
import sys

from asn1crypto import cms
from dateutil.parser import parse
from pypdf import PdfReader


class AttrClass:
    """Abstract helper class"""

    def __init__(self, data, cls_name=None):
        self._data = data
        self._cls_name = cls_name

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            value = self._data[name]
        except KeyError:
            value = None
        else:
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                return AttrClass(value, cls_name=name.capitalize() or self._cls_name)
        return value

    def __values_for_str__(self):
        """Values to show for "str" and "repr" methods"""
        return [
            (k, v) for k, v in self._data.items()
            if isinstance(v, (str, int, datetime.datetime))
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        """String representation of object"""
        values = ", ".join([
            f"{k}={v}" for k, v in self.__values_for_str__()
        ])
        return f"{self._cls_name or self.__class__.__name__}({values})"

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<{self}>"


class Signature(AttrClass):
    """Signature helper class

    Attributes:
        type (str): 'timestamp' or 'signature'
        signing_time (datetime, datetime): when user has signed
            (user HW's clock)
        signer_name (str): the signer's common name
        signer_contact_info (str, None): the signer's email / contact info
        signer_location (str, None): the signer's location
        signature_type (str): ETSI.cades.detached, adbe.pkcs7.detached, ...
        certificate (Certificate): the signers certificate
        digest_algorithm (str): the digest algorithm used
        message_digest (bytes): the digest
        signature_algorithm (str): the signature algorithm used
        signature_bytes (bytest): the raw signature
    """

    @property
    def signer_name(self):
        return (
            self._data.get('signer_name') or
            getattr(self.certificate.subject, 'common_name', '')
        )


class Subject(AttrClass):
    """Certificate subject helper class

    Attributes:
        common_name (str): the subject's common name
        given_name (str): the subject's first name
        surname (str): the subject's surname
        serial_number (str): subject's identifier (may not exist)
        country (str): subject's country
    """
    pass


class Certificate(AttrClass):
    """Signer's certificate helper class

    Attributes:
        version (str): v3 (= X509v3)
        serial_number (int): the certificate's serial number
        subject (object): signer's subject details
        issuer (object): certificate issuer's details
        signature (object): certificate signature
        extensions (list[OrderedDict]): certificate extensions
        validity (object): validity (not_before, not_after)
        subject_public_key_info (object): public key info
        issuer_unique_id (object, None): issuer unique id
        subject_uniqiue_id (object, None): subject unique id
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.subject = Subject(self._data['subject'])

    def __values_for_str__(self):
        return (
            super().__values_for_str__() +
            [('common_name', self.subject.common_name)]
        )


def parse_pkcs7_signatures(signature_data: bytes):
    """Parse a PKCS7 / CMS / CADES signature"""
    content_info = cms.ContentInfo.load(signature_data).native
    if content_info['content_type'] != 'signed_data':
        return None
    content = content_info['content']
    certificates = content['certificates']
    # each PKCS7 / CMS / CADES could have several signatures
    signer_infos = content['signer_infos']
    for signer_info in signer_infos:
        # the sid key should point to the certificates collection
        sid = signer_info['sid']
        digest_algorithm = signer_info['digest_algorithm']['algorithm']
        signature_algorithm = signer_info['signature_algorithm']['algorithm']
        signature_bytes = signer_info['signature']
        # signed attributes is a list of key, value pairs
        # oversimplification: normally we have no repeated attributes
        signed_attrs = {
            sa['type']: sa['values'][0] for sa in signer_info['signed_attrs']}
        # find matching certificate, only for issuer / serial number
        for cert in certificates:
            cert = cert['tbs_certificate']
            if (
                sid['serial_number'] == cert['serial_number'] and
                sid['issuer'] == cert['issuer']
            ):
                break
        else:
            raise RuntimeError(
                f"Couldn't find certificate in certificates collection: {sid}")
        yield dict(
            sid=sid,
            certificate=Certificate(cert),
            digest_algorithm=digest_algorithm,
            signature_algorithm=signature_algorithm,
            signature_bytes=signature_bytes,
            signer_info=signer_info,
            **signed_attrs,
        )


def get_pdf_signatures(filename):
    """Parse PDF signatures"""
    reader = PdfReader(filename)
    fields = reader.get_fields().values()
    signature_field_values = [
        f.value for f in fields if f.field_type == '/Sig']
    for v in signature_field_values:
        # - signature datetime (not included in pkcs7) in format:
        #   D:YYYYMMDDHHmmss[offset]
        #   where offset is +/-HH'mm' difference to UTC.
        v_type = v['/Type']
        if v_type in ('/Sig', '/DocTimeStamp'):  # unknow types are skipped
            is_timestamp = v_type == '/DocTimeStamp'
            try:
                signing_time = parse(v['/M'][2:].strip("'").replace("'", ":"))
            except KeyError:
                signing_time = None
            # - used standard for signature encoding, in my case:
            # - get PKCS7/CMS/CADES signature package encoded in ASN.1 / DER format
            raw_signature_data = v['/Contents']
            # if is_timestamp:
            for attrdict in parse_pkcs7_signatures(raw_signature_data):
                if attrdict:
                    attrdict.update(dict(
                        type='timestamp' if is_timestamp else 'signature',
                        signer_name=v.get('/Name'),
                        signer_contact_info=v.get('/ContactInfo'),
                        signer_location=v.get('/Location'),
                        signing_time=signing_time or attrdict.get('signing_time'),
                        signature_type=v['/SubFilter'][1:],  # ETSI.CAdES.detached, ...
                        signature_handler=v['/Filter'][1:],
                        raw=raw_signature_data,
                    ))
                    yield Signature(attrdict)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print(f"Usage: {sys.argv[0]} <filename>")
        sys.exit(1)
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    for signature in get_pdf_signatures(filename):
        print(f"--- {signature.type} ---")
        print(f"Signature: {signature}")
        print(f"Signer: {signature.signer_name}")
        print(f"Signing time: {signature.signing_time}")
        certificate = signature.certificate
        print(f"Signer's certificate: {certificate}")
        print(f"  - not before: {certificate.validity.not_before}")
        print(f"  - not after: {certificate.validity.not_after}")
        print(f"  - issuer: {certificate.issuer}")
        subject = signature.certificate.subject
        print(f"  - subject: {subject}")
        print(f"    - common name: {subject.common_name}")
        print(f"    - serial number: {subject.serial_number}")
```

Update 2024-02-03: PDF timestamps are handled now, too. Code improvements. Example output added.

Example output:

```bash
$ ./getpdfdignatures.py example-signed-timestamped.pdf 
--- signature ---
Signature: Signature(digest_algorithm=sha256, signature_algorithm=sha256_rsa, content_type=data, type=signature, signing_time=2024-02-03 08:33:38+01:00, signature_type=ETSI.CAdES.detached, signature_handler=Adobe.PPKLite)
Signer: EIDAS CERTIFICADO PRUEBAS - 99999999R
Signing time: 2024-02-03 08:33:38+01:00
Signer's certificate: Certificate(version=v3, serial_number=96891622000445695554354105786026700712, common_name=EIDAS CERTIFICADO PRUEBAS - 99999999R)
  - not before: 2020-11-05 13:04:20+00:00
  - not after: 2024-11-05 13:04:20+00:00
  - issuer: Issuer(country_name=ES, organization_name=FNMT-RCM, organizational_unit_name=Ceres, common_name=AC FNMT Usuarios)
  - subject: Subject(country_name=ES, serial_number=IDCES-99999999R, given_name=PRUEBAS, surname=EIDAS CERTIFICADO, common_name=EIDAS CERTIFICADO PRUEBAS - 99999999R)
    - common name: EIDAS CERTIFICADO PRUEBAS - 99999999R
    - serial number: IDCES-99999999R
--- timestamp ---
Signature: Signature(digest_algorithm=sha256, signature_algorithm=sha256_rsa, content_type=1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.1.4, signing_time=2024-02-03 07:36:09+00:00, type=timestamp, signature_type=ETSI.RFC3161, signature_handler=Adobe.PPKLite)
Signer: self-signed-tsa
Signing time: 2024-02-03 07:36:09+00:00
Signer's certificate: Certificate(version=v3, serial_number=143954336546707891453596703528087303323516137098, common_name=self-signed-tsa)
  - not before: 2020-12-16 07:03:36+00:00
  - not after: 2030-12-14 07:03:36+00:00
  - issuer: Issuer(country_name=BE, organization_name=DSS TEST PKI, organizational_unit_name=TEST PKI, common_name=self-signed-tsa)
  - subject: Subject(country_name=BE, organization_name=DSS TEST PKI, organizational_unit_name=TEST PKI, common_name=self-signed-tsa)
    - common name: self-signed-tsa
    - serial number: None
```

The signature and time stamping was done using [DSS Demonstration WebApp](https://ec.europa.eu/digital-building-blocks/DSS/webapp-demo/). Timestamps are much like signatures.

Comment: and what way I can locate time stamp info please? I need locate information about Time Stamp Authority (TSA) and information about signing time from this TSA. In PDF structure viewer I see this information only in "V (dict)" but unstructured... Thanks.

Comment: @Mato: the code detects and parses now time stamps too.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @mkl in comments below this may not work in all cases, and without a minimal sample untested with OP data (but did work with my sample files).

The OP simply wanted to detect if signed files and Sig named contents. *" Signatures without email would be exception cases."*

The problem with SOME signed files is they are encrypted. So simple search is more difficult. Thus to simplify the detection speedily place a copy of the decompressed (and thus decrypted) files in a work folder (for later deletion). There are many command line tools to decompress a file.pdf, such as `qpdf` or others.

Now you have all your potential candidates, you can scan for `Sig` and then from that output determine Unsigned (as in the first case) or Signed as in the second copy. By judicious filtering of `/Name`s you can extract the plain text for listings. `/Name(gerald.holmann@qoppa.com)/Location(Atlanta, GA, USA)`

[image]

Comment: *"The problem with signed files is they are encrypted."* - Not necessarily. Some signing services by default do so (to further restrict changes to the signed PDFs) but that is not required by the specification.

Comment: The **Name** entry is optional anyways and its value *should be used only when it is not possible to extract the name from the signature.*

Comment: Yes, but the email addresses need not necessarily be stored in the **Name** entry. Actually the OP does not clearly state where exactly they see the email address. If it's in the signature panel, it can also be read from the subject DN of the signer certificate. If it's in the signature widget, it may be only in the normal appearance there, maybe even rendered on a custom bitmap.

Comment: @mkl: Thanks. I updated the example code to get the signer name from /Name if it's given, else, defaults to the certificate's common name (which also may be empty). The complete X500 subject is available as signature.certificate.subject.