# How I can extract PDF digital signature information using in python?

Tags: python, digital-signature

I am trying to create a Python code to obtain the information from a digital signature within a PDF file, but with the following code below, it does not recognize the available digital signatures within the PDF files.

```py
import os
import re
import base64
import ssl
import glob

pdf_dir = r'C:\Users\est.matheus.ro\Desktop\Certificados\push\pdfs'
cert_regex = re.compile(b'-----BEGIN PKCS7-----\r?\n.+?\r?\n-----END PKCS7-----', re.DOTALL)

for filepath in glob.glob(os.path.join(pdf_dir, '*.pdf')):

    with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:
        pdf_content = f.read()

    cert_match = cert_regex.search(pdf_content)
    if cert_match is None:
        print(f'Digital signature not found in file {filepath}.')
        continue
    cert_data = cert_match.group(0)

    try:
        pkcs7 = ssl.PKCS7(cert_data)
        pkcs7_bio = ssl.BIO.MemoryBuffer(cert_data)
        pkcs7.verify(None, pkcs7_bio)
    except ssl.Error:
        print(f'Error decoding the digital signature of file {filepath}.')
        continue

    signers = pkcs7.get0_signers(ssl.X509.X509_Stack())
    if len(signers) < 1:
        print(f'Invalid digital signature in file {filepath}.')
        continue
    signer = signers[0]
    subject = signer.get_subject()
    name = subject.commonName
    cpf = subject.serialNumber
    date = signer.get_notBefore().decode('ascii')
    validity = signer.get_notAfter().decode('ascii')
    print(f'Digital signature found in file {filepath}.')
    print('Name: ', name)
    print('CPF: ', cpf)
    print('Issuance date: ', date)
    print('Expiration date: ', validity)
```

I would like this code to extract the following digital certificate information:

- **Signer name**
- **Serial Number (CPF in Brazil)**
- **Issuance date**
- **Expiration date**

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following StackOverflow answer: [How to locate digital signatures in PDF files with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72556172/how-to-locate-digital-signatures-in-pdf-files-with-python/77515811#77515811)

Normally, we don't read the "issuance date" but the `certificate.validity.not_before` date. Expiration date would be `certificate.validity.not_after`